# What does parameters limit and maxLevel mean in Neo4j apoc query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

By reading the official Neo4j documentation, I can't understand what does the two parameters `limit` and `maxLevel` mean in a `apoc.path.subgraphnodes`.

https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/path-finding/path-expander/

Anyone can help me ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`maxLevel` is basically the depth of the expansion. `maxLevel:2` means up to two expansions from the starting node.

`limit` limits the total results returned from the call, once this many results are found, then it will stop looking further.

So as an example, if we had a social graph, and you wanted to find the first 3 :Doctor nodes, within 10 expansions of you (this uses breadth first expansion by default), you might use something like:

```
MATCH (me:Person {id:12345})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(me, {maxLevel:10, limit:3, labelFilter:'Doctor'}) YIELD node
RETURN node
```

And there might be thousands of :Doctor nodes within 10 hops, but because of the `limit:3`, once 3 are found it will stop trying to find more.